# UDP сервер-клиент. Как провести вычисление?

Tags: udp, java, сокет

Привет)
Как можно сделать так, чтобы вычисление происходило между клиентом и сервером по протоколу UDP?

Н-р, Сервер передает выражение 1+2. 
Клиент получает это сообщение, и он в ответ дает  серверу 3.
Вот листинг кода, если надо:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.File;
class kurs
{
    public static int serverPort = 666;
    public static int clientPort = 999;
    public static int buffer_size = 1024;
    public static DatagramSocket ds;
    public static byte buffer[] = new byte[buffer_size];
    public static void TheServer() throws Exception
    {
        int pos=0;
        while(true)
        {
            int c=System.in.read();
            switch(c){
                case -1:
                    System.out.println("Server Quits.");
                    return;
                case '\r':
                    break;
                case '\n':
                 ds.send(new DatagramPacket(buffer,pos,InetAddress.getLocalHost(),clientPort));
                    pos=0;
                    break;
                default: buffer[pos++]=(byte)c;

            }
        }
            }

    public static void TheClient() throws Exception{
        while(true)
        {
            DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length);
            ds.receive(p);
            System.out.println(new String(p.getData(),0,p.getLength()));
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
            throws Exception{
        if(args.length==1){
            ds = new DatagramSocket(serverPort);
            TheServer();

        }
        else{
            ds=new DatagramSocket(clientPort);
            TheClient();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Есть другая идея, Например, серверу передается команда, 1. То он вычисляет выражение 2+2=4. Как реализовать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Вопрос закрыт, сделал на C#.

Answer (score 2):

Гы-гы, а препод у вас с фантазией!

Паттерн решения такой:

1. Клиент посылает строку
2. Сервер принимает строку
3. Строка засовывается в парсер - синтаксический анализатор. Анализатор строит [синтаксическое дерево](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D1%E8%ED%F2%E0%EA%F1%E8%F7%E5%F1%EA%E8%E9_%E0%ED%E0%EB%E8%E7) которое и собственно дает ответ чему равно 2+1
4. Результат посылается обратно клиенту в виде строки
5. Клиент получает строку и выводит на печать

В общем самое сложное и интересное здесь как раз написание парсера :)

Comment: Если клиент знает, что будет сложение чисел)

Comment: Да какая разница - парсер вернет синтаксическую ошибку и все.